# Chi square of 0.00, but acceptable (other) fit indices?

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit, structural-equation-modeling

I am running a path analysis for a sample of 75 participants using RStudio. I am comparing two models and have to decide which one to use (I am in favor of Model A, but because of the Chi-square: 0, I am confused about whether I can use it or not). All of my variables correlate with each other, and they are:

**z** and **q**: independent variables
**x** and **y**: independent variables (possible mediators) and finally
**a** and **b**: dependent variables

**model<-' x ~ z + q, y ~ z + q, a ~ z + q + x + y, b ~ z + q + x + y, z ~~ z, q ~~ q, z ~~ q, a ~~ a, b ~~ b, y ~~ y, x ~~ x , x ~~ y'**

Output of Model A:
Chi-square (df): .00 (0) / RMSEA: .00  90%[ .00, .00] / SRMR: .00 / CFI: 1.00 / TLI: 1.00 / AIC: 1624.414 / ECVI: 0.411

Output of Model B:
Chi-square (df): 3.41 (1) p> .05 / RMSEA: .18  90%[ .00, .40] / SRMR: .03 / CFI: .97 / TLI: .68 / AIC: 2009.015 / ECVI: 0.587

**Do you think Model A is a poor model and therefore Model B should be used? Or can I accept Model A and draw conclusions from it?
Looking forward to hearing your thoughts!**

Comment: Zero degrees of freedom is a genuine problem, but you need to supply enough information to help us determine why this has occurred. Most likely you are overfitting your data, but that can only be a guess.

Comment: @whuber thanks for your response! I added my variables and the code I have used. If you need more info I can add that :) Looking forward to hearing your thoughts!